# I have a 2003 Dodge Caravan with 36,000 on it . Auto repairman says age of car means more repairs

Tags: car

I've recently bought another new battery, new tires, new brakes, replaced sway bar links and bushings.  Auto repairman says the age of the car is starting to take it's toll, even though I only drive about 1500 miles a year since I've retired.  Do I keep this car or start fresh with a new car which will probably be my last car.  A new car shouldn't have any problems with the low mileage I have.

Comment: If you want to change cars, I'd think about getting a used car that is quite new but has a lot of mileage. The mileage will make it cheap, but isn't a problem if you only add 1500 miles a year. And a car that's 2 years old and has 100,000 miles has been driven long distances most of the time, where wear and tear per mile is less.

Comment: I can imagine that a 11-year-old car with 36,000 miles on it might need a new battery (age-related) and possibly new tires (rubber is going bad or tires are reaching the end of their rated mileage of (typically) 40,000 miles) but _new_ brakes seems a little unusual. Are you sure that it was not just worn brake pads, or resurfacing of the rotors instead of a complete brake replacement?

Comment: You may want to do a sanity check with the folks at http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/, sometimes the repairmen exaggerate the problems to get you to spend more money.

Comment: New brake disks is actually not unusual on low-milage vehicles. If the car isn't driven enough to dry them out and polish off the surface rust, corrosion can do a surprising amountvof damage to them.

Comment: @DilipSarwate If the car has spent any time in standing water, this can also affect the brakes.

Comment: Er, wait a moment... if its okay to send [this payment posting](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/64395/need-help-to-find-the-amount-more-for-a-payment/64397#64397) from Mechanics to Personal Finance and Money on stack exchange, why isn't this auto repair related posting pushed back the other way?  That hardly seems fair.  But I will say.. quality answers are provided here anyway!  Nicely done...

Answer (score 4):

Given that 36,000 is not many miles for a 2003 model, it seems that wear-and-tear from usage is not what's taking its toll, which is quite unusual in my experience.  The "age" of a car is sometimes a reference to mileage rather than years, so it'd be good to clarify whether the mechanic specifically meant your car or was just making a general point about older vehicles.

However, if it's starting to regularly cost money in terms of replacing old, structural parts (brakes and tyres aside), then it might be worth looking at a newer car.  I think a brand new model would be unnecessary given your predicted annual mileage, but a well-looked-after used car would be a sensible choice.  If it's got a full service history and has done something like 10k miles per year then you'll probably be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Age (as opposed to mileage or hard use) affects a car in the following ways:

- Rubber deteriorates.  The tires need to be replaced eventually.  Seals don't seal as well.  Hoses become brittle.  You need to have the brakes, fluids, and gas lines checked occasionally.
- Plastics deteriorate.
- Glues deteriorate.  You will start to get rattles in the dashboard and doors.
- Paint jobs wear off.  Washing and waxing your car can help temporarily.
- Corrosion.  Salt spray can make things rust out.  Battery terminals can corrode, possibly requiring battery replacement and/or alternator replacement.  Even aluminum wheels can corrode.  Electrical features may stop working, such as lights, wipers, and windows.
- Light bulbs burn out.

Also, newer cars tend to have more powerful engines.  Some old cars just aren't peppy enough to merge into freeway traffic.  I don't think a 2003 Caravan is likely to have this problem.

All of your recent purchases are consistent with this list.  Fortunately, each of the new parts should last a few years.  If you keep up with the regular maintenance, and set aside money ahead of time for the inevitable replacements, it should be cheaper to keep your car in good shape than to buy a new car.  Furthermore, 2003 Caravans are nice looking, roomy vehicles with decent track records.  Chrysler doesn't make them the way they used to anymore.

Answer (score 2):

One concrete way to evaluate this:

Ask a mechanic to evaluate it as if he was considering buying it, in its current condition, for his daughter. You want him to give you a list of everything the car will need soon and how much that will cost, and what he'd tell her was a fair price for it.

He'll probably charge you about $200 for this service, unless prices have gone up more than I expect.

Then look at those numbers and ask yourself whether you can really come out ahead by replacing this vehicle with another -- remembering that if you buy someone else's used car it may have many of the same issues -- or if it's going to be cheaper to keep this car on the road.

You may or may not want to factor in gas milage difference.

Often, as long as it can be trusted not to break down hundreds of miles from home, keeping even an older car is financially better than replacing it. You may want go change cars anyway, but this may help you estimate how much that decision will cost you.

(My current set of wheels is about 2 years older than yours and only about twice the milage. There are some rust issues developing, and the front suspension's probably due for replacement. I don't have any immediate plans to jettison it.)